# Python reading from CSV file in python 2.7 but not python 3.6. What do i have to do to make it work in 3.6

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, csv

I have some code which i coded in python 2.7, however I need it to work for 3.6 and when i run it i get this error and i am not sure why.

```
import csv
def ReadFromFile():
  with open('File.csv', 'r') as File:
    cr = csv.reader(File)
    for row in cr:
      Name = row[0]
      Gender = row[1]
      print(Name + Gender)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    ReadFromFile()
  File "F:/Test.py", line 6, in ReadFromFile
    Name = row[0]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I am using the same code saved on a memory stick with the file in 2.7 i get my desired out come of it being read but in 3.6 i am stuck with the error. Thanks for any help

Edit: Added Print 
After adding print i got

```
ELIZABETHFemale
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    ReadFromFile()
  File "F:/Test.py", line 6, in ReadFromFile
    Name = row[0]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

So it gave me the first line but nothing more

Comment: Show us a reproducing example.

Comment: what would you get if you print out row?

Comment: Added edits to show what i get if i add print

Comment: You are missing the point. Don't print out `Name` or `Gender`. Just print `row`. No subscript. The whole row by itself. You should see the problem, and it has nothing to do with whether you use Python 2.7 or 3.6.

Comment: Also think about what it means for a list index to be out of range. If you have a list called `mylist` and it has 3 elements, then those elements can be referenced by `mylist[0]`, `mylist[1]`, and `mylist[2]`. If you try `mylist[3]`, you get a list index out of range error. So what is that telling you about `row`? How many elements does `row` have if `row[0]` is producing list index out of range?

Comment: The problem with that is it does work with 2.7 so why would the range change between versions

Comment: do you mind just type `print(row)` before `Name = row[0]` and show us the *printed* results?

Comment: And what's in your `File.csv`?

Comment: Just did print(row) and it gave me ['ELIZABETH', 'Female']
[]['SAM', 'Male'] I dont understand why though because according to notepad there are no extra lines

Answer (score 1):

Python's CSV module has changed how it wants the files you pass to it to be opened. You want to avoid the file object doing any newline transformation because some CSV formats allow embedded newlines within quoted fields. The `csv` module will do its own newline normalization, so the usual universal newline handling the file object does is redundant.

This is mentioned in [the `csv.reader` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader), where it is talking about the file argument:

> If *csvfile* is a file object, it should be opened with `newline=''`.

So for your code, try changing `open('File.csv', 'r')` to `open('File.csv', 'r', newline='')`.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried pandas?
I think you may want to use something like

```
import pandas as pd

def ReadFromFile():
    df = pd.read_csv('File.csv')
    for row in df:
      Name = row[0]
      Gender = row[1]
      print(Name + Gender)
```

Comment: remember you can encapsulate your code in \``` to format it correctly